# Как при A_I в mysql оставить не затронутым первые 100 значений

Tags: mysql

Как при Auto Increment в mysql оставить не затронутым первые 100 значений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;